# ByteToMessageDecoder netty

Tags: netty

I implemented a decoder that extends ByteToMessageDecoder. I will be able to see the correct message format in decode function but not in channelRead function (another class which extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter). What I receive in channelRead function is still a byteBuffer. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Did you add your decoder before your `ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter`?

Comment: Yes. Do I need to change the order? I did but I got another error: An exceptionCaught() event was fired, and it reached at the tail of the pipeline. It usually means the last handler in the pipeline did not handle the exception.
java.lang.NullPointerException: null

Comment: I figured that out. Thanks